# Identify the functions in python

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

I am trying to parse the python file using 'ast' and I am able to successfully do it.

Now I need to differentiate the default methods of 'dict' and 'list'

Example :
    I can have a method like below

```
classa = new TestClassA
classa.test()
```

But If I call a method of 'dict' / 'list'

```
some_dict = dict() 
some_dict.keys()
```

I need to identify the default methods of 'dict' and 'list' and skip it

**One way is**: I can have all the methods in the configuration file and I can skip it, But If there a better to identify it please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by "default methods"?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I mean to say the functions provided by dict and list like dict.update / dict.keys() etc.,

Comment: `classa = new TestClassA` is not valid Python; it should rather be `classa = TestClassA()`.

Comment: To clarify: As I undertand the question, you want to parse a Python file and identify all the methods of "proper" classes (by whatever definition) as opposed to methods provided by builtin types like `dict`? This will probably not be possible with static code analysis, as the type of a variable might be determined at run-time. (You _could_ blacklist all builtin methods, but what if another class defines a method of the same name?)

Comment: @tobias_k yes correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of members defined by a class by calling `dir(class_name)`. So for example `dir(list)` and `dir(dict)` will give all of the members of each of these two classes. Note that this includes special names like `__init__` as well as fields. You will still have to determine which ones you actually want to skip.

Answer (score 2):

You could get a glimpse of methods and attributes of a given object in two simple ways:

1. Using `dir()` function on the object or instance of an object
2. Using `help()` function

**1. dir() function**

```
>>> d = dict()
>>> type(d)
<class 'dict'>
>>> for attribute in dir(d):
...   print(attribute)
... 
__gt__
clear
copy
fromkeys
get
items
keys
pop
popitem
setdefault
update
values
```

**2. help() function**

This is probably the most elegant way to print the attributes and functions of an object

```
class dict(object)
 |  dict() -> new empty dictionary
 |  dict(mapping) -> new dictionary initialized from a mapping object's
 |      (key, value) pairs
 |  dict(iterable) -> new dictionary initialized as if via:
 |      d = {}
 |      for k, v in iterable:
 |          d[k] = v
 |  dict(**kwargs) -> new dictionary initialized with the name=value pairs
 |      in the keyword argument list.  For example:  dict(one=1, two=2)
 |  
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
 |  __contains__(self, key, /)
 |      True if D has a key k, else False.
 |  
 |  __delitem__(self, key, /)
 |      Delete self[key].
 |  
 |  __eq__(self, value, /)
 |      Return self==value.
 |  
 |  __ge__(self, value, /)
 |      Return self>=value.
 |  
 |  __getattribute__(self, name, /)
 |      Return getattr(self, name).
 ...
 ...
 |  copy(...)
 |      D.copy() -> a shallow copy of D
 |  
 |  fromkeys(iterable, value=None, /) from builtins.type
 |      Returns a new dict with keys from iterable and values equal to value.
 |  
 |  get(...)
 |      D.get(k[,d]) -> D[k] if k in D, else d.  d defaults to None.
 |  
 |  items(...)
 |      D.items() -> a set-like object providing a view on D's items
 |  
 |  keys(...)
 |      D.keys() -> a set-like object providing a view on D's keys
 |  
 |  pop(...)
 |      D.pop(k[,d]) -> v, remove specified key and return the corresponding value.
 |      If key is not found, d is returned if given, otherwise KeyError is raised
 |  
 |  popitem(...)
 |      D.popitem() -> (k, v), remove and return some (key, value) pair as a
 |      2-tuple; but raise KeyError if D is empty.
 |  
 |  setdefault(...)
 |      D.setdefault(k[,d]) -> D.get(k,d), also set D[k]=d if k not in D
 |  
 |  update(...)
 |      D.update([E, ]**F) -> None.  Update D from dict/iterable E and F.
 |      If E is present and has a .keys() method, then does:  for k in E: D[k] = E[k]
 |      If E is present and lacks a .keys() method, then does:  for k, v in E: D[k] = v
 |      In either case, this is followed by: for k in F:  D[k] = F[k]
 |  
 |  values(...)
 |      D.values() -> an object providing a view on D's values
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data and other attributes defined here:
 |  
 |  __hash__ = None
```